# PHP/T-SQL: Cannot update column with umlauts in name

Tags: php, sql-server, t-sql

I am having problems with updating a column with umlauts in the name. It works fine if I rename it, but it's a third party database and I cannot rename it permanently, because I do not know what SP:s, update or maintenance operations are/will be performed for the DB. On sql server cmd I can update it.

Here is the plain query (Yhtiö causes the update to fail)

```
UPDATE [third].[dbo].[partydb]
SET 
[Yhtiö] = '".$yritys."'
WHERE 
[ID] = '".$id."'
```

Error:

> Invalid column name 'Yhtiö'.

Comment: try to put UTF-8 as character set while creating database

Comment: can you create a view in your db?

Comment: The DB is not created by me, but a 3rd party software, so I should not fiddle with it.  SQL-server is not the issue, since I can update, delete insert on its command window, but when I run a PHP script with UPDATE -clause it fails. So the problem lies with PHP:s ability to understand SQL-columns with umlauts (umlauts in data are ok but apparently umlauts in column name are not)

Comment: For some reason the 3rd party software uses umlauts in column name.